# how to solve/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_columnfamilies/system-schema_columnfamilies-tmp-ic-131-Index.db file not exist in cassendra

Tags: cassandra

any one tell me  how to solve/var/lib/Cassandra/data/system/schema_columnfamilies/system-schema_columnfamilies-tmp-ic-131-Index.db file not exist in Cassandra.

Which shows the following error:

]
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/local/system-local-tmp-ic-326-Index.db (Permission denied)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SequentialWriter.(SequentialWriter.java:73)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SequentialWriter.open(SequentialWriter.java:108)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SequentialWriter.open(SequentialWriter.java:103)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableWriter$IndexWriter.(SSTableWriter.java:442)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableWriter.(SSTableWriter.java:92)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$FlushRunnable.createFlushWriter(Memtable.java:517)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$FlushRunnable.writeSortedContents(Memtable.java:465)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$FlushRunnable.runWith(Memtable.java:448)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.DiskAwareRunnable.runMayThrow(DiskAwareRunnable.java:48)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/local/system-local-tmp-ic-326-Index.db (Permission denied)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.(RandomAccessFile.java:241)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SequentialWriter.(SequentialWriter.java:69)
        ... 12 more
 INFO 12:33:01,778 Writing Memtable-schema_columns@1367224066(24717/24717 serialized/live bytes, 398 ops)
ERROR 12:33:01,776 Exception in thread Thread[FlushWriter:2,5,main]
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_keyspaces/system-schema_keyspaces-tmp-ic-86-Index.db (Permission denied)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SequentialWriter.(SequentialWriter.java:73)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SequentialWriter.open(SequentialWriter.java:108)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SequentialWriter.open(SequentialWriter.java:103)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableWriter$IndexWriter.(SSTableWriter.java:442)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableWriter.(SSTableWriter.java:92)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$FlushRunnable.createFlushWriter(Memtable.java:517)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$FlushRunnable.writeSortedContents(Memtable.java:465)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$FlushRunnable.runWith(Memtable.java:448)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.DiskAwareRunnable.runMayThrow(DiskAwareRunnable.java:48)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_keyspaces/system-schema_keyspaces-tmp-ic-86-Index.db (Permission denied)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.(RandomAccessFile.java:241)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SequentialWriter.(SequentialWriter.java:69)
        ... 12 more
ERROR 12:33:01,783 Exception in thread Thread[FlushWriter:3,5,main]
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_columns/system-schema_columns-tmp-ic-81-Index.db (Permission denied)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SequentialWriter.(SequentialWriter.java:73)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SequentialWriter.open(SequentialWriter.java:108)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SequentialWriter.open(SequentialWriter.java:103)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableWriter$IndexWriter.(SSTableWriter.java:442)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableWriter.(SSTableWriter.java:92)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$FlushRunnable.createFlushWriter(Memtable.java:517)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$FlushRunnable.writeSortedContents(Memtable.java:465)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$FlushRunnable.runWith(Memtable.java:448)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.DiskAwareRunnable.runMayThrow(DiskAwareRunnable.java:48)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_columns/system-schema_columns-tmp-ic-81-Index.db (Permission denied)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.(RandomAccessFile.java:241)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SequentialWriter.(SequentialWriter.java:69)
        ... 12 more
 INFO 12:33:01,786 Writing Memtable-schema_columnfamilies@1938605158(22187/22187 serialized/live bytes, 369 ops)
ERROR 12:33:01,789 Exception in thread Thread[FlushWriter:4,5,main]
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_columnfamilies/system-schema_columnfamilies-tmp-ic-131-Index.db (Permission denied)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SequentialWriter.(SequentialWriter.java:73)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SequentialWriter.open(SequentialWriter.java:108)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SequentialWriter.open(SequentialWriter.java:103)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableWriter$IndexWriter.(SSTableWriter.java:442)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableWriter.(SSTableWriter.java:92)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$FlushRunnable.createFlushWriter(Memtable.java:517)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$FlushRunnable.writeSortedContents(Memtable.java:465)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$FlushRunnable.runWith(Memtable.java:448)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.DiskAwareRunnable.runMayThrow(DiskAwareRunnable.java:48)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_columnfamilies/system-schema_columnfamilies-tmp-ic-131-Index.db (Permission denied)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.(RandomAccessFile.java:241)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SequentialWriter.(SequentialWriter.java:69)
        ... 12 more

Comment: It looks like a permission problem, try running with sudo

Comment: Thanks for your response.but if i running with sudo it also throw the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it by changing the ownership of some folders using the following command:

`sudo chown -R cassandra:cassandra  /var/lib/cassandra/`

After doing this `cqlsh` worked for me.